# Save user provided number with prompt from first message?

Tags: c#, botframework

Hi I'm using C# in Visual studio with Microsoft's bot emulator and I'm wondering how can I prompt the user for a number input in the first message and store it in the conversation. Here's what I have so far in my MessagesController:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.LuisHandler());
        }
        else
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            if (activity.MembersAdded.Any(o => o.Id == activity.Recipient.Id))
            {
                PromptDialog.Number(activity,setUserID,"Please enter your number code","Error please enter the number again",3,"",0,999);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

This is obviously not the correct way to do it since both the activity and setUserId attributes display an error, how can I fix this?

Also, this my SetUserId method:

```
public void setUserID(int id, Activity act)
    {
        IDialogContext cxt = act;
        cxt.UserData.SetValue("userId", id);
    }
```

Where id will be the number provided by the user and I save it in the context of the conversation to use it in queries later, how can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I prompt the user for a number input in the first message and store it in the conversation.

The `PromptDialog.Number()` method accepts ***IDialogContext*** object as a parameter, so we can not directly call it from Messages controller (outside of Dialog) to prompt for a number.

```
public static void Number(IDialogContext context, ResumeAfter<long> resume, string prompt, string retry = null, int attempts = 3, string speak = null, long? min = null, long? max = null);
```

To achieve the requirement: prompting the user for a number input in the first message and storing it in the conversation, you can try the following sample as an workaround.

***In Messages controller:***

```
//...

else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
{
    // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
    // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
    // Not available in all channels

    IConversationUpdateActivity update = message;
    var client = new ConnectorClient(new System.Uri(message.ServiceUrl), new MicrosoftAppCredentials());
    if (update.MembersAdded != null && update.MembersAdded.Any())
    {
        foreach (var newMember in update.MembersAdded)
        {
            if (newMember.Id != message.Recipient.Id)
            {
                var reply = message.CreateReply();
                reply.Text = $"Welcome {newMember.Name}! Please enter your number code!";
                client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);

            }
        }
    }

}
```

***In dialog:***

```
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
bool thenumberisentered = false;

    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;

        if (!thenumberisentered)
        {
            string pattern = @"^(?:0|[1-9]\d{0,2})$";
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rgx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern);

            if (rgx.IsMatch(activity.Text))
            {
                //save the number code as user data here 

                thenumberisentered = true;

                await context.PostAsync($"The number code you entered is: {activity.Text}");
            }
            else
            {
                PromptDialog.Number(context, setUserID, "Please enter your number code", "Error please enter the number again", 2, "", 0, 999);
                return;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"You sent {activity.Text}");
        }

        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private async Task setUserID(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<long> result)
    {
        long numcode = await result;

        await context.PostAsync($"The number code you entered is: {numcode}");

        thenumberisentered = true;

        //save the number code as user data here 

        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

}
```

***Test result:***

[image]